# Bot returning error "payment required"

Tags: azure, botframework

I am running a bot deployed to an azure webapp. 
The bot runs fine in local debugging, and it runs fine in the web test client in the Azure portal.

I can connect to the bot from the bot framework emulator, and I can access its default html front page from a browser, but when I POST a message to the REST api it returns the following error.

I'm puzzled by the status code "PaymentRequired".  I can't figure out where this comes from based on the stack trace.  My bot is in the S1 Standard pricing tier. When I visit the App Service Plan blade, it says I'm in the Default0 (Free: 0 Small) plan.  When I visit Change App Service Plan it says "No App Service Plans Found". For what it's worth, I don't think it's a LUIS issue because LUIS works fine when I connect from other clients.

```
Buffer="{ 
    "message": "An error has occurred.", 
    "exceptionMessage": "Operation returned an invalid status code 'PaymentRequired'", 
"exceptionType": "Microsoft.Bot.Connector.ErrorResponseException", 
"stackTrace":
    " at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Conversations.<ReplyToActivityWithHttpMessagesAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.ConversationsExtensions.<ReplyToActivityAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.AlwaysSendDirect_BotToUser.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IBotToUser-PostAsync>d__4.MoveNext() in D:\a\1\s\CSharp\Library\Microsoft.Bot.Builder\ConnectorEx\BotToUser.cs:line 124
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.InputHintQueue.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IMessageQueue-QueueMessageAsync>d__4.MoveNext() in D:\a\1\s\CSharp\Library\Microsoft.Bot.Builder\ConnectorEx\BotToUser.cs:line 184
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.AutoInputHint_BotToUser.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IBotToUser-PostAsync>d__3.MoveNext() in D:\a\1\s\CSharp\Library\Microsoft.Bot.Builder\ConnectorEx\BotToUser.cs:line 146
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.MapToChannelData_BotToUser.<PostAsync>d__3.MoveNext() in D:\a\1\s\CSharp\Library\Microsoft.Bot.Builder\ConnectorEx\BotToUser.cs:line 295
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.LogBotToUser.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IBotToUser-PostAsync>d__4.MoveNext() in D:\a\1\s\CSharp\Library\Microsoft.Bot.Builder\ConnectorEx\IActivityLogger.cs:line 131
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogContext.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IBotToUser-PostAsync>d__12.MoveNext() in D:\a\1\s\CSharp\Library\Microsoft.Bot.Builder\Dialogs\DialogContext.cs:line 87
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Extensions.<PostAsync>d__14.MoveNext() in D:\a\1\s\CSharp\Library\Microsoft.Bot.Builder\Dialogs\IDialogContext.cs:line 150
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at myBot.ExceptionHandlerDialog`1.<DisplayException>d__7.MoveNext() in C:\myBot\Dialogs\ExceptionHandlerDialog.cs:line 71
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at myBot.ExceptionHandlerDialog`1.<ResumeAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\myBot\Dialogs\ExceptionHandlerDialog.cs:line 47
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.ThunkResume`1.<Rest>d__5.MoveNext() in D:\a\1\s\CSharp\Library\Microsoft.Bot.Builder\Dialogs\DialogTask.cs:line 164
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Wait`2.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IWait<C>-PollAsync>d__19.MoveNext() in D:\a\1\s\CSharp\Library\Microsoft.Bot.Builder\Fibers\Wait.cs:line 0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Frame`1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IFrameLoop<C>-PollAsync>d__9.MoveNext() in D:\a\1\s\CSharp\Library\Microsoft.Bot.Builder\Fibers\Fiber.cs:line 0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Fiber`1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IFiberLoop<C>-PollAsync>d__16.MoveNext() in D:\a\1\s\CSharp\Library\Microsoft.Bot.Builder\Fibers\Fiber.cs:line 0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
 at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Wait`2.Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.IAwaiter<T>.GetResult() in D:\a\1\s\CSharp\Library\Microsoft.Bot.Builder\Fibers\Wait.cs:line 378
 at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Chain.LoopDialog`1.<ResumeAsync>d__3.MoveNext() in D:\a\1\s\CSharp\Library\Microsoft.Bot.Builder\Dialogs\Chain.cs:line 752
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.ThunkResume`1.<Rest>d__5.MoveNext() in D:\a\1\s\CSharp\Library\Microsoft.Bot.Builder\Dialogs\DialogTask.cs:line 164
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Wait`2.<Microsoft-Bot-TRUNCATED..."
```

Comment: `My bot is in the S1 pricing plan` Do you mean that your bot service is using S1 Standard [pricing tier](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/bot-service/)?

Comment: Please add more details about your current bot configuration: `bot service pricing` in your bot channel registration AND `App Service plan/pricing tier` in your Web app overview

Comment: Yes, as noted the bot is configured in the S1 Standard pricing tier.  I'll add details about the app service plan.

Comment: Are you using ngrok?

Comment: Yes, ngrok is configured. I'm also using an AAD-backed event hub, and logging to an MSA-backed storage account (the bot/webapp is MSA-backed). I don't see any obvious issues with these services.

Comment: It's worth adding that earlier in the day yesterday everything worked.  I'm not sure where I'm bumping up against any quotas.

Comment: The only time I've seen '402 Payment Required' is when Ngrok limits come into play.  Try restarting ngrok.  https://ngrok.com/pricing

Comment: @EricDahlvang that was likely the issue. I got myself an auth token and restarted the bot framework emulator.  Feel free to write it up as an answer for extra karma.  (If not I'll add the answer in the next day or two).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The only time I've seen '402 Payment Required' is when Ngrok limits come into play. Try restarting ngrok.

https://ngrok.com/pricing

Comment: Adding an ngrok auth token and restarting the bot framework emulator resolved the issue.  Thanks!

Comment: Just restarting the bot emulator worked for me as well thanks

Comment: Visual Studio -> Stop Debbuging, Emulator -> Restart - help for me

Answer (score 1):

Happened to me as well, with the same failure when the bot tries to publish the welcome screen (at the Emulator). Restarting the Emulator resolved it.